# LXD init cannot be used at this time

Tags: lxd

With a machine newly upgraded to 16.04, I run "lxd init" and it returns with "LXD init cannot be used at this time".  What causes this error message?  And what do I have to fix so that I can run "lxd init"?

I removed lxc1, uninstalled lxd and reinstalled it, all without success.

I finally uninstalled lxd with a "purge" option and removed the /var/lib/lxd and /var/log/lxd directories, before reinstalling lxd and lxd-client.  Now I can run "lxd init", but it didn't create the lxdbr0 bridge.

Comment: after the purge and reinstall, I was able to run the "lxd init" as well as the "dpkg-reconfigure -p medium lxd".  Then the lxdbr0 was created when I started the first container.

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions here, I'll try to help.

`lxd init` requires the LXD installation to be brand new with no containers already created. The command you're looking for is `dpkg-reconfigure -p medium lxd` which will allow for reconfiguration of the network bridge.

You can also use this command to address your second issue and try again to create the bridge.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to do the uninstall purge and apt-get autoclean. The only difference is that I set my /etc/network/interfaces back to the original and did a uninstall purge on bridge-utils as well. That worked for me and I was able to do lxd init.